# PHP Concatenation Operator space necessary in URL?

Tags: php

I noticed that most examples of using the concatenation operator show a white space before and after the "**.**"

For example:

```
header('Location: http://google.com?c1=' . $var1 . '&c2=' . $var3);
```

But this seems to work fine without the whitespace in this example:

```
header('Location: http://google.com?c1='.$var1.'&c2='.$var3);
```

Are there any issues with using the concatenation operator the second way?

Comment: It's just a matter of convention

Comment: That's just for readability. More readable even is leaving out the concatenation and utilizing double quotes: `header("Location: http://google.com?c1=$var1&c2=$var3");` given an IDE with reasonable syntax highlighting. `http_build_query()` would also make more sense.

Comment: @mario and use of curly braces if there are any array vals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the whitespaces are added to improve readability.

Just like

```
if($var=='test'){echo'ok';}
```

and

```
if ($var == 'test') 
{
    echo  'ok';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The spaces aren't needed but they make it easier to read.

[php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#88827)